# Store User Input Values in File for Another Script

Tags: python

I have a script that writes user input values from questions to a txt file. Another script needs to be able to open that file and read in those answers.
Ive been trying to write the values in a x=y format in txt file but when called in the other script it throws an error saying the variable is not defined. This leads me to believe I just dont have my temporary txt file formatted correctly for python to read the information. How would I want to store the multiple variables and values in the txt file for python to be able to read them in as a variable name?

**Here is how the first script stores my values. (single line)**

timeIn=18 January 2019 11:39:40 supportID=Andy branch=Bristow clientID=Cindy Lou reason=grinch stole christmas

**Here is the error I get when trying to read in the values by variable name.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script2.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.write('[Time In] '+ timeIn)
NameError: name 'timeIn' is not defined
```

**My question is how would I want to format these in the txt file to be read in by another script?**

**edit 1: Im opening the txt file in the second script this way**

```
t=open("testtmp.txt","r")
```

**edit 2: I am not writing the values just as themselves (x) on individual lines. I am now trying to read those values in to be written to another file.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS IS HOW I SOLVED MY ISSUE (.txt format):**

First, I wrote in the original values with a line break separating them.

```
t=open("nbsstmp.txt", "w")
t.write(timeIn+' \n')
t.write(supportID+' \n')
t.write(branch+' \n')
t.write(clientID+' \n')
t.write(problem+' \n')
t.close()
```

Then, I was able to read them back in the following way.

```
t=open("nbsstmp.txt","r")
f=open("Support_Access_Log.txt","a")
timeIn=(t.readlines((1)))
a=(str(timeIn))
supportID=(t.readlines(2))
b=(str(supportID))
branch=(t.readlines(3))
c=(str(branch))
clientID=(t.readlines(4))
d=(str(clientID))
problem=(t.readlines(5))
e=(str(problem))

f.write('[Time In] ')
f.write(a.replace("['","").replace("']","").replace("\\n",""))
f.write(' [Support ID] ')
f.write(b.replace("['","").replace("']","").replace("\\n",""))
f.write(' [Branch] ')
f.write(c.replace("['","").replace("']","").replace("\\n",""))
f.write(' [Support Client] ')
f.write(d.replace("['","").replace("']","").replace("\\n",""))
f.write(' [Reason] ')
f.write(e.replace("['","").replace("']","").replace("\\n",""))
f.close()
t.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of key value data would be easier to work with in a json file.

You can use the the library json to work with it.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Using a text file you are just working with a string, so you would need to parse data into usable format after reading it.